# MVC .NET Adding View Error DB code first

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I just made an MVC .net website and i'm getting an error while trying to make a View for Index...

I get the error:

> "there was an error running the selected code generator: "unable to
>   retrieve metadata for "MVC_Voetbal.Model.Club". The context is being
>   used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file
>   for either Database First or Model First development. ......"

I have searched alot, and found a lot of the same errors, but never saw the solution that helps me with my project..

I get this error while trying to make a View that lists all the clubs in my database. My code:

```
private ClubService clubService;        

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var clubs = clubService.All();
    return View(clubs);
}
```

Connection string in MVC_Voetbal.Model App.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BierenEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelBier.csdl|res://*/ModelBier.ssdl|
        res://*/ModelBier.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider 
        connection string=&quot;data source=MSI;initial catalog=Bieren;
        integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Connection string in MVC_Voetbal  Web.config:

```
<add name="BierenEntities1" connectionString="Data 
    Source=PC_DENZEL\SQLVIVES;
    Initial Catalog=VoetbalDB;
    Integrated Security=True" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string try changing the provider name, I think the fault is trying to tell you that it is trying to use EF code first, but it has been build DB first. In a project I had done using DB first the connection string provider name was

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

so change that in your web.config and see if it works?

**EDIT**
And in your Model app.config which would suggest it was built with a designer?

Comment: When I change the providerName, it gives the same error. It was sqlClient by default so I changed it to EntityClient to try and solve my problem (was a solution on another thread), but it didn't work.. & the Model app.config was default when I created the database model.